# gparted without GUI / X

Tags: gparted, parted

Is there a CLI gparted version without GUI / X?

parted shows warnings like the following when resizing / moving partitions:

> WARNING: you are attempting to use parted to operate on (resize) a file system.
>   parted's file system manipulation code is not as robust as what you'll find in
>   dedicated, file-system-specific packages like e2fsprogs.  We recommend
>   you use parted only to manipulate partition tables, whenever possible.
>   Support for performing most operations on most types of file systems
>   will be removed in an upcoming release.

or

> Error: file system has incompatible feature enabled. Compatible features are has_journal, dir_index, filetype, sparse_super and large_file Use tune2fs or debugfs to remove features.

gparted can move / resize them. I thought they were using the same libraries. Is there any alternative to parted?

Answer (score 4):

The filesystem resize ability was long crufty and unmaintained in `parted`, which is why it was removed in the 3.0 release several years ago.  If you update to the latest parted 3.2, it has a `resizepart` command that only resizes the partition, and you have to use another filesystem specific utility to resize the filesystem within the partition.  In the case of ext[234] that is `resize2fs`.  When expanding the partition you resize the partition first, then the filesystem.  When shrinking, you reverse the order, and make sure you leave a little extra room just in case; you can always re-expand the fs after resizing the partition.

Comment: my assumption after observing this has been that gparted is calling out to resize2fs etc., and that does seem to be the case.  E.g. see the last question on [this 2014 interview](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/news.php?item=180).